# Whats is going wrong to create a category template

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I want to create the page that lists the categories then link to the template that contains the posts in each category.

I created my page to list the post categories:

src/pages/categories.js - it's working!

```js
import React from "react"
import { Link, graphql } from "gatsby" //highlight-line
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import ArchiveSidebar from '../components/archive/ArchiveSidebar'

import {
  PageContent,
  StyledH2,
  
  StyledReadMore
} from './styles/archiveStyles'

export default function Categories({ data }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Categories" />
      <div className="container">
      <div className="row" style={{ marginBottom: '40px' }}>
      
      <ArchiveSidebar />
     
      <PageContent className="col-lg-9">
      <h1>My WordPress Categories</h1>
      {data.allWpCategory.edges.map((edges) => (
        <div key={edges.slug}>
          {/* highlight-start */}
          <Link to={edges.node.slug}>
          <StyledH2 
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edges.node.name }} 
          />
          </Link>
        
          {/* highlight-end */}
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: edges.slug }} />
          <StyledReadMore to={edges.node.slug}>
                Go!
              </StyledReadMore>
        </div>
        
        
      ))}
      </PageContent>
      </div>
        </div>
        
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allWpCategory{
        edges{
            node {
            name
            slug
      }
    }
}
  }
`
```

[image]

But I'm not able to create the template that lists each category.

The templates for the programmatically blog posts and pages work, but I can't make the templates for the categories work.

src/templates/post-category.js

```js
import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export default function Category({ data }) {
  const category = data.allWpCategory.nodes[0]
  
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div>
        <h1>{category.name}</h1>
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: category.slug }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
export const query = graphql`
  query {
    allWpCategory {
      edges{
        node{
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

gastby-node.js

```js
const path = require(`path`)



exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  return graphql(`
  {
    allWpCategory{
      edges{
        node{
          name
          slug
        }
      }
    }
    }
  `).then((result) => {
  
    result.data.allWpCategory.edges.forEach(edge => {
      
        createPage({
          path: edge.node.slug,
          component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/post-category.js`),
          context: {
            name: edge.node.name,
            
          }
        })
      
    })

  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two things here:

- Your `/categories` page should be a page, so you will create a page query there and you will list your categories there. Create a page named `categories.js` and add the following:

  ```
    import { graphql, Link } from 'gatsby';
    import React from 'react';
    import Layout from '../components/layout';

    export default function Categories ({ data }) {
      const categories = data.allWpCategory.edges;

      return (
        <Layout>
          <div>
            {
              categories.map(category=>{
                return  <Link key={category.name} to={category.slug}> // note that slashes in the slug, you may need to add it
                  <h1>{category.name}</h1>
                </Link>;
              })
            }
          </div>
        </Layout>
      );
    }

    export const query = graphql`
        query {
            allWpCategory {
                edges{
                    node{
                       name
                       slug
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    `;
  ```

Basically, you are making a page query to list all your categories. The specific link to each category will work because you are creating them in your `gatsby-node.js`

- However, following the last point, if you want to get the specific data for each category, that is a template (like you did in `post-category`) that is a separate query that should be managed using the context, since you need to query the specific data for each category using the `name` field. Something like:

```
   import React from "react"
   import Layout from "../components/layout"
   import { graphql } from "gatsby"
   
   export default function Category({ data }) {
    const category = data.wpCategory;

    console.log("your data is here-->", category)  
   
     return (
       <Layout>
         <div>
           <h1>{category.name}</h1>
           <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: category.slug }} />
         </div>
       </Layout>
     )
   }
   export const query = graphql`
     query($name: String!) {
       wpCategory(name: { eq: $name} ) {
             name
             slug
           }
     }
   
  `
```

Basically, the `name` passed through context is the item that will filter your data in  `wpCategory(name: { eq: $name})`. Notice that I've changed the a little bit the query, you may need to check out that it's working since I don't know how's your data structure.

For further details check https://www.gatsbyjs.com/tutorial/part-seven/.

Comment: Thank you but i'm completely lost.

Comment: Your node it's creating pages properly. You only miss the part where you filter the data for each category. Use the `localhost:8000/___graphql` to get the template query

Comment: @RicardodePaula I've added an extended version of what's going on and how to achieve it. You need to create a page query to list all categories and then, each category will have the data using a filtered query using the context.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to do this.

Comment: for everyone looking ro query categories: query GetCategory($category: String) {
  categories: allWpPost(sort: {fields: [date]}, filter: {categories: {nodes: {elemMatch: {name: {eq: $category}}}}}) {
    nodes {
      title
      excerpt
      slug
      date(formatString: "DD, MMMM, YYYY", locale: "pt")
    }
  }
}

Comment: That query will always depends on your data structure and your filesystem. That's why you should look at `localhost:8000/___graphql` to test it. As I said, the query may be different than mine.